# Mesh as list of seperated lines

Tags: plotting, graphics, mesh

Startingpoint is the following 3D plot:

```
test = Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2 + #3^2] &}, Mesh -> 10, 
  PlotStyle -> None]
```

[image]

I would like to create a list with the different meshlines. When I look at

```
FullForm[test]
```

I can see a GraphicsComplex. For me it's not easy to understand how to generate the different lines. I would like to get a output like

```
{Line[{2.14285705102040, 0.42857158163265, 
  0.794611641214728}, {2.357142734693877, 0.42857158163265, 
  0.846940533910772}, {2.571428418367346, 0.42857158163265, 
  0.892131358058375}, {2.78571410204081, 0.42857158163265, 
  0.929803242524781}, {2.9999997857142855, 0.42857158163265, 
  0.959638686277861}],Line[{},{},{}].....
```

Who has a suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

```
lines = Cases[Normal[test], Line[pts_] :> Line[pts], -1]
```

Or maybe need to remove the boundary.

```
plot=Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2 + #3^2] &}, Mesh -> 10, 
  PlotStyle -> None,BoundaryStyle->None]
lines = Cases[Normal[plot], Line[pts_] :> Line[pts], -1]
```